# How to replace flash animations like this?

Tags: javascript, flash, animation

What is the technology used here? (don't worry, its not porn despite the url)

http://www.dirtyphonebook.com/dashboard/425-205-1921

It animates a lot like Flash, but when I right click there's no Flash menu.

Is it something like canvas or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of images, svg and [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/)

( http://raphaeljs.com/ )

Comment: Interesting library. Will check it out.

It even works in IE, wow.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug shows it's SVG:

```
<div id="dashboard_container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="875" height="315">
    <desc>
      Created with Raphaël
    </desc>
    <defs/>
    <image x="0" y="0" width="875" height="315" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/dashboard.1269592899.jpg"/>
    <image x="185.75" y="125.125" width="16.5" height="60.75" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/arrow.1269592899.gif" r="NaN" transform="rotate(-10.7522, 194, 174)"/>
    <image x="300.2" y="113.1" width="17.6" height="64.8" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/arrow.1269592899.gif" r="NaN" transform="rotate(19.6304, 310, 168)"/>
    <image x="425" y="95" width="22" height="81" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/arrow.1269592899.gif" transform="rotate(-60.8551, 437, 160)"/>
    <image x="552.87" y="112.885" width="18.259999999999998" height="67.22999999999999" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/arrow.1269592899.gif" r="NaN" transform="rotate(53.5478, 564, 166)"/>
    <image x="670.75" y="125.125" width="16.5" height="60.75" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/arrow.1269592899.gif" r="NaN" transform="rotate(73.5362, 679, 174)"/>
    <image x="341" y="207" width="57" height="45" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/red_glow.1269592899.png"/>
    <image x="473" y="207" width="57" height="45" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://img17.dirtyphonebookstatic.com/images/dashboard/red_glow.1269592899.png"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Read the [basic info about SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)